# Jmeter and Filewriter - adding a date + timestamp to the filename

Tags: jmeter, filewriter, beanshell

I have created a jmeter that places an order on my site and records the order status and confirmation number. Once the order is booked, I use a BeanShell PostProcessor to print out the extracted variables to a file. I would really like to be able to add a date to the filename, but I have not been able to find a way to do it.

This is what my Bean Shell Post Processor looks like:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\JMeter\\Results\\log.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(vars.get("scriptName"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.write("STATUS: " + vars.get("status"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.write("Confirmation Number: " + vars.get("ConfirmationNumber"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.write("");
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.write("");
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

I have tried inserting variables into the filename, but I suspect I have been doing it wrong, because no files are even being created.

Full disclaimer (which may not be necessary given my sample code above): I am not a code person, so please excuse the shoddy code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a property at the beginning which you can append to your filename later.

```
${__P(UNIQUEID,${__time(YMDHMS)})}
```

Then you can change your line to the following

```
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(vars.get("CWD") + "/JMeter/results/log${UNIQUEID}.csv", true);
```

In the above code, CWD is another variable that I set at the beginning which points to current directory from which Jmeter islaunched.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; 

String sCWd = new String(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir());
log.info("CWDString=" + sCWd.replace("\\", "/"));
vars.put("CWD", sCWd.replace("\\\\", "/"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Selva. This is exactly what I needed, but I am not sure how to set the ${__P(UNIQUEID,${__time(YMDHMS)})} property so I can use it. I tried adding it to the user.properties file, but it doesn't look like it was the way to go.

Comment: Using your suggestion I figured out a different way to achieve this, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add a 'User Defined variables' configuration element at the top of your test plan and add a row and define it. Name: UNIQUEID, Value : ${__P(UNIQUEID,${__time(YMDHMS)})}